# Shared Functions in CI2: Helper? Library?

Tags: function, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm still quite new to OOP, and have been learning-as-I-go with CodeIgniter2+Doctrine2.

I have a couple of shared functions that are handy in various areas of my project, so I'd like to call them.  In procedural PHP I'd just stick them in a library file and call them.  But that's not working for me now..

```
include 'function_library.php';
$name = $this -> function_library -> generate_male_name();
```

> Message: Undefined property: Turn::$function_library

I even read somewhere that you needed to use `call_function()`, but that only got me:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Turn::call_function()

So I figured maybe I should load it as a helper.

```
$this->load->helper('character_helper');
echo generate_male_name();
```

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   /PATH/systemFolder/helpers/character_helper.php
>   on line 19

Line 19:

> $query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("select max(u.id) from ORM\Dynasties2\Malenames u");

I considered setting it up as a Library, but honestly that begins to get a little over my head in terms of Classes and such.  I have not tried it.

Here is the entirety of that function:

```
function generate_male_name() {
        $query = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("select max(u.id) from ORM\Dynasties2\Malenames u");
         $result = $query->getSingleResult();
         //echo $result2[1];
         $highval = $result[1];
         $random_name = rand(1,$highval);
         //echo $random_name;
         $name = $this->doctrine->em->find('ORM\Dynasties2\Malenames', $random_name);
         return $name->getName();     
    }
```

How can I do this?

Edit:

Tried a few additional things, still no success.

I put my function_library in third_party, and did:

```
$this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/function_library/');
$name = $this -> generate_male_name();
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Turn::generate_male_name()

or `$name = $this -> function_library -> generate_male_name();`

> Message: Undefined property: Turn::$function_library

I'm not crazy about calling it in autoloader, I don't need it *everywhere*, and that seems less than efficient.

I've read up on libraries, but as I said, Classes are quickly over my head and creating a new library seems more than a little daunting to me.

***What's the best solution here?  How do I share a few functions?  Is a library the way I need to go, or am I just missing something minor in trying to make a helper or shared_functions thing work?***

Comment: Try autoloading the helper in the config file.  You could also try putting your library in the third_party folder, load it and call it from there.

Comment: In codeigniter you can call the instance of codeigniter using 

    $ci =& get_instance();

Not sure about doctrine though

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**May be not an answer**, only talking about `CodeIgniter`

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   /PATH/systemFolder/helpers/character_helper.php on line 19

This happens when you try to use `CI` instance with `$this` keyword outside of object context (when `CI` is not instantiated). Observing the error above I can guess that you are using `$this` inside the helper `character_helper.php` that is located inside the `helpers` folder but outside of `CI` object context. To use `CI` object you must instantiate the `CI` using

```
$ci = & get_instance();
```

and use `$ci` instead of `$this` in your helper.

If you want to use your helper inside any controller then you can load it normally inside your controller as usual, i.e.

```
$this->load->helper('character_helper');
```

and if your helper has a function `generate_male_name` then you can call it inside your controller as follows

```
generate_male_name();
```

> $this, however, only works directly within your controllers, your
>   models, or your views.

[**Creating CodeIgniter Libraries.**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)